# Learning C - Compiling error allocating pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm new to C and trying to compile this simple code, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct Node{
        int value;
        struct Node *next;
    };

    struct Node* x;
    struct Node* y;
    struct Node* z;

    x = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    y = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    z = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    return 0;        
}
```

The compiler is complaining about the use of an `undeclared identifier ‘Node’`:

```
x = malloc(sizeof(Node));
y = malloc(sizeof(Node));
z = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Comment: Use `struct Node` or `x = malloc(sizeof(*x));`

Comment: or you can `typedef strunct Node { int value; struct Node *next; } Node;` but recommend @hmjd's solution.

Comment: Might want to `free()` that when you're done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sizeof(struct Node)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO and the wonderful world of C!

A few pointers for you:

Syntax-ically there's no problem with defining a struct inside a function, but typically it's defined outside so that it can be used in other functions. For example:

```
main(){ 
  struct nodedef{vars};
  add_to_node(node var);
}

add_to_node(node var)
{
   // How can I add a to a node when I don't know what that is?
}
```

The main problem with your code is that you aren't correctly referencing your node later on, if I declaire:

```
struct me {
    int i;
};
```

Then anytime I reference this type of struct, I have to explicitly say `struct` again:

```
struct me myself;
myself = malloc(sizeof(struct me));
myself.i = 5;
```

The way to avoid this reuse of the `struct` keyword is to use the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct me {
    int i;
}m;

m myself;
myself = malloc(sizeof(m));
myself.i = 5;
```

Last point is anytime you allocate some memory via `malloc()` make sure you call `free()` to release that memory:

```
free(myself);
```

Or else you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`struct Node` should be used to refer to the structure. If you want the code above works, an alternative is `typedef`-ing the `struct Node` structure as

```
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```